# how to acess the frame widgets from another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

(my code is generating this error
to_text.insert(END,'Click and Say...')
**NameError: name 'to_text' is not defined**
this prog is running fine if i am creating the frame after main window and 
then #calling only temp_fun() .but my code need to access frame widgets )

```
from tkinter import *
def frame1():
    f1=Frame(winchat).pack()    
    to_text=Text(f1).pack()
def temp_fun():
    to_text.insert(END,'Click and Say...')
winchat=Tk()
frame1()
temp_fun()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep reference of to_text so you can access it on the other function, for that you can try using it as a global var.

```
from tkinter import *
to_text = None #<--- declaring it first.
def frame1():
    f1=Frame(winchat)
    f1.pack()   
    to_text=Text(f1)
    to_text.pack()
def temp_fun():
    to_text.insert(END,'Click and Say...')
winchat=Tk()
frame1()
temp_fun()
```

once you declare like that, you can reference it across any function.

Comment: This still wont work. You need to call pack() on a separate line.

Comment: You example should work fine however it seams kinda pointless to have a function like this when the widgets are just going to be in the global name space anyway. Its probably best just to write them in global in the first place.

Comment: Totally agree, just trying to point out what was wrong with his code, this isn't probably his final implementation anyway, he was just trying to recreate the error in a similar way, perhaps.

Comment: Fair enough. You are answering the very specific issue based of of how his code is currently set up. I just wanted to point it out as it seams unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to create the frame and text box in the global name space.
This way you can edit them from other functions. Keep in mind if you want to edit a widget later you will need use `pack()` on a separate line or else it will return `None` when you try to edit the widgets.

Take a look at the below example.

```
from tkinter import *


def temp_fun():
    global to_text # tell the function you want to edit this item in global
    to_text.insert(END,'Click and Say...')

winchat=Tk()

f1=Frame(winchat)
f1.pack()    
to_text=Text(f1)
to_text.pack()

temp_fun()

winchat.mainloop()
```

You do not need to add global in the function in this case because python will eventually check global as `to_text` is not defined in the function however I add the global here anyway for accuracy.

Comment: Don't forget to call pack on a separate line on f1! ;)

Comment: @divancontreras `f1` does not need to have pack called on a 2nd line. There is nothing in the OPs example that says they will need to edit the frame later or add to the frame later.

Comment: Well, then it seams kinda pointless to have it assign in to a variable.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I just realized that the widget is getting place in the root window when it receives `None` from the frame... You learn something every day.